# How do I trisect an angle using tkz-euclide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Using the `\tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)` command in `tkz-euclide`, you can bisect an angle. How can I cut an angle in three or more equal parts?

Comment: Off-topic: just to inform (for those who don't know): this is one of those 3 classical problems. The construction with compass and ruler (without measures) is not possible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection

Answer (score 6):

To trisect an angle, try something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoint(6,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(1,4){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C)

% Get the angle and define two new points that lie on the trisectors.
\tkzFindAngle(A,B,C) \tkzGetAngle{at}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center B angle 1*\at/3](A) \tkzGetPoint{T1}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center B angle 2*\at/3](A) \tkzGetPoint{T2}

% Draw the trisectors.
\tkzSetUpLine[color=blue!70]
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](B,T1)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](B,T2)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The resulting image:

[image: a trisected angle]

Extending this procedure, you can n-sect an angle: just adapt `1*\at/3` to be `k*\at/n` for `k` from 1 to n-1.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly overkill, but you could adapt Morley's theorem, and use trilinear coordinates that form the equilateral triangle whose vertices can be used to describe the trisectors. Unfortunately, the conversion from trilinear coordinates to `tkzEuclide`'s barycentric coordinate system involves some fiddling.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\def\tkzfiddle#1{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1<0?#1+360:#1}\let#1=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#1>180?180-#1:#1}\let#1=\pgfmathresult%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(35:4){B}
\tkzDefPoint(105:4){C}

\tkzFindAngle(B,A,C) \tkzGetAngle{A}
\tkzFindAngle(C,B,A) \tkzGetAngle{B}
\tkzFindAngle(A,C,B) \tkzGetAngle{C}
\tkzCalcLength(A,B) \tkzGetLength{c}
\tkzCalcLength(B,C) \tkzGetLength{a}
\tkzCalcLength(C,A) \tkzGetLength{b}

\tkzfiddle\A\tkzfiddle\B\tkzfiddle\C
\pgfmathparse{max(\a,\b,\c)}\let\n=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{\a/\n}\let\a=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{\b/\n}\let\b=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{\c/\n}\let\c=\pgfmathresult

\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=\a*1,B={\b*2*cos(\C/3)},C={\b*2*cos(\B/3)})
\tkzGetPoint{A'}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A={\a*2*cos(\C/3)},B=\b*1,C={\c*2*cos(\A/3)})
\tkzGetPoint{B'}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A={\a*2*cos(\B/3)},B={\b*2*cos(\A/3)},C=\c*1)
\tkzGetPoint{C'}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon[red](A,B',C')
\tkzDrawPolygon[green](B,C',A')
\tkzDrawPolygon[blue](C,B',A')
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,A',B',C')
\foreach \label/\anchor in {A/below left, B/right, C/above,
  A'/above right, B'/left, C'/below right}%
    {\tkzLabelPoints[\anchor](\label)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amusingly, I needed this to construct a graphic in a proof of... Morley's theorem :)

Answer (score 0):

tkz-euclide is useful! However, I try to use it as little as possible (I am lazy to remember more commands). I change something from Lynn's code (see above)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,1.5);
\coordinate (C) at (2,5);
\draw (A) node[below]{A}--
      (B) node[left]{B}--
      (C) node[left]{C};

\tkzFindAngle(A,B,C) \tkzGetAngle{at}

\coordinate (T1) at ($(B)!3cm!\at/3:(A)$);
\coordinate (T2) at ($(B)!3cm!2*\at/3:(A)$);

\draw[blue] (B)--(T1);
\draw[red] (B)--(T2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]